# dplyr and tidyr: convert long to wide format and arrange columns

Tags: r, tidyr, r-factor

I'm creating a `shiny app` in which the user will upload a .csv file that contains several variables. Using `dplyr`, I will `select` the first four variables, shown below, and convert them from long format.

**DATA**

```
df <- read.table(text = c("
Customer    Rate    Factor  Power
W1  6   TK1 5
W2  3   TK1 0
W3  1   TK1 0
W4  2   TK1 0
W5  4   TK1 0
W6  8   TK1 0
W7  5   TK1 0
W8  7   TK1 3
W1  6   TK2 0
W2  3   TK2 1
W3  1   TK2 0
W4  2   TK2 5
W5  4   TK2 0
W6  8   TK2 0
W7  5   TK2 0
W8  7   TK2 3
W1  6   TK3 0
W2  3   TK3 5
W3  1   TK3 1
W4  2   TK3 0
W5  4   TK3 0
W6  8   TK3 0
W7  5   TK3 0
W8  7   TK3 0
W1  6   TK4 0
W2  3   TK4 3
W3  1   TK4 0
W4  2   TK4 0
W5  4   TK4 0
W6  8   TK4 0
W7  5   TK4 0
W8  7   TK4 0
W1  6   TK5 1
W2  3   TK5 0
W3  1   TK5 5
W4  2   TK5 0
W5  4   TK5 1
W6  8   TK5 0
W7  5   TK5 0
W8  7   TK5 0
W1  6   TK6 0
W2  3   TK6 0
W3  1   TK6 0
W4  2   TK6 0
W5  4   TK6 0
W6  8   TK6 0
W7  5   TK6 5
W8  7   TK6 0
W1  6   TK7 0
W2  3   TK7 0
W3  1   TK7 0
W4  2   TK7 0
W5  4   TK7 0
W6  8   TK7 3
W7  5   TK7 3
W8  7   TK7 0
W1  6   TK8 0
W2  3   TK8 0
W3  1   TK8 1
W4  2   TK8 0
W5  4   TK8 0
W6  8   TK8 3
W7  5   TK8 0
W8  7   TK8 0
W1  6   TK9 0
W2  3   TK9 0
W3  1   TK9 0
W4  2   TK9 0
W5  4   TK9 5
W6  8   TK9 0
W7  5   TK9 0
W8  7   TK9 0
W1  6   TK10    0
W2  3   TK10    0
W3  1   TK10    0
W4  2   TK10    0
W5  4   TK10    0
W6  8   TK10    5
W7  5   TK10    0
W8  7   TK10    0
W1  6   TK11    0
W2  3   TK11    0
W3  1   TK11    0
W4  2   TK11    0
W5  4   TK11    0
W6  8   TK11    0
W7  5   TK11    0
W8  7   TK11    3
W1  6   TK12    0
W2  3   TK12    0
W3  1   TK12    0
W4  2   TK12    0
W5  4   TK12    0
W6  8   TK12    0
W7  5   TK12    0
W8  7   TK12    5"), header = T)
```

I used the code below to convert from long to wide format

**LONG TO WIDE**

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df_wide <-  df %>%
  tidyr::spread(Factor, Power)
```

**RESULT**

```
> df_wide
  Customer Rate TK1 TK10 TK11 TK12 TK2 TK3 TK4 TK5 TK6 TK7 TK8 TK9
1       W1    6   5    0    0    0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
2       W2    3   0    0    0    0   1   5   3   0   0   0   0   0
3       W3    1   0    0    0    0   0   1   0   5   0   0   1   0
4       W4    2   0    0    0    0   5   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
5       W5    4   0    0    0    0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   5
6       W6    8   0    5    0    0   0   0   0   0   0   3   3   0
7       W7    5   0    0    0    0   0   0   0   0   5   3   0   0
8       W8    7   3    0    3    5   3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

The wide format is showing the levels of `Factor` variable as `TK1` and then `TK10`

```
> levels(df$Factor)
 [1] "TK1"  "TK10" "TK11" "TK12" "TK2"  "TK3"  "TK4"  "TK5"  "TK6"  "TK7"  "TK8"  "TK9"
```

I want the levels of Factor to be from TK1, TK2 till TK12

I can solve as below

```
df$Factor <- factor(df$Factor, levels = c("TK1", "TK2" , "TK3" , "TK4",  "TK5" , "TK6" , "TK7" , "TK8" , "TK9", "TK10", "TK11", "TK12"))
```

However, the levels of Factor variable will be a function of the user's input. It might be 14, 15 or 20.

**QUESTION**

Is there any way to arrange the levels of Factor column from lowest to highest regardless of the user's input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can change it to `factor` with `levels` specified

```
df %>%
  mutate(Factor = factor(Factor, levels = paste0("TK", 1:12))) %>%
  spread(Factor, Power)
```

---

Or make it more dynamic, we `extract` the non-numeric and numeric part into separate columns ('Factor1', 'Factor2'), change the 'Factor' to `factor` with `levels` specified by `paste`ing the sequence of `min` to `max` values in 'Factor2' with that of the first character value in 'Factor1', remove the 'Factor1' and 'Factor2', and `spread`.

```
library(tidyr)
res <- df %>%
         extract(Factor, into = c("Factor1", "Factor2"), "(\\D+)(\\d+)",
                                   remove = FALSE, convert=TRUE) %>% 
         mutate(Factor = factor(Factor, levels = paste0(Factor1[1], 
                              min(Factor2):max(Factor2)))) %>% 
         select(-Factor1, -Factor2) %>% 
         spread(Factor, Power)
head(res, 2)
#  Customer Rate TK1 TK2 TK3 TK4 TK5 TK6 TK7 TK8 TK9 TK10 TK11 TK12
#1       W1    6   5   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0    0    0    0
#2       W2    3   0   1   5   3   0   0   0   0   0    0    0    0
```

Comment: Many thanks for your time and help. What if another user has 17 levels instead of 12. I want a code that can work regardless of how many levels in the user's input

Comment: @aelwan Updated the post

Comment: Thanks Akrun. I got this error

Error in `[.data.frame`(., Factor, into = c("Factor1", "Factor2"), "(\\D+)(\\d+)",  : 
  unused arguments (into = c("Factor1", "Factor2"), remove = FALSE, convert = TRUE)

Comment: @aelwan I am using `tidyr_0.4.1.9000`, and `dplyr_0.4.3.9001`.  With your data, I am not getting any error.